# Second dropdown of cascading dropdown is not populating

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am hitting the controller but when I get back to the javascript the `function (courses)` embedded in the `$.getJSON()` function is skipped and the debugger goes to the end of the `$.getJSON()` function and the data for the second dropdown list (list of courses) is not populating. I'm not sure why.

Here are my controllers:

```
public JsonResult GetCourses(int facilityId)
{
    return Json(GetCoursesSelectList(facilityId), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

private SelectList GetCoursesSelectList(int id)
{
    var Courses = db.Courses.Distinct().Where(a => a.FacilityId == id).ToList();
    SelectList list = new SelectList(Courses);
    return list;
}
```

My javascript is as follows:

```
$("#ddlFacilities").change(function () {
            var selectedFacility = $(this).val();            
            if (selectedFacility !== null && selectedFacility !== '') {
                $.getJSON("/RoundDetail/GetCourses", { FacilityId: selectedFacility },
                    function (courses) {
                    alert(course.Course_Name);
                    var coursesSelect = $('#ddlCourse');
                    coursesSelect.empty();
                    $.each(courses, function (index, course) {
                        coursesSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                            value: course.CourseId,
                            text: course.Course_Name
                        }));
                    });
                });
            }
            });
```

Comment: use browser dev tools (ex: firebug) and check what error do you get when request time...

Comment: I am using the browser dev tools in Chrome.  What do you mean by request time?

Comment: Your JSON call is returning an error (failed), so it skips the success method. Check the network/XHR in the chrome console.

Comment: if there is an error, when you fire the dropdownlist change method chrome say you what error do you get.

Comment: May be error case sensitive. in script code `FacilityId` and controller `facilityId`

Comment: I am relatively new debugging javascript.  I will have to research how to use XHR

Comment: FacilityId is capitalized in the database

Comment: It looks like the XHR error states there is s.content is false in the line: xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null )

Comment: Either change the method in the controller to receive a FacilityId parameter or change the jQuery parameter to facilityId.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the script error while loading the cascading dropdown. If you couldn't make it, try the alternative way to load the values. I usually follow the below approach for loading cascading dropdownlist.

[Script]

```
function SetdropDownData(sender, args) {           

        $('#ShipCountry').live('change', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Home/GetCities',
                data: { Country: $('#ShipCountry').val() },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#ShipCity option').remove();
                    $.each(data, function (index, val) {                           
                            var optionTag = $('<option></option>');
                            $(optionTag).val(val.Value).text(val.Text);
                            $('#ShipCity').append(optionTag);

                    });
                }
            });
        });

  }
```

[Controller]

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Cities(string Country)  // ShipCity is filtered based on the ShipCountry value  
    {
        var Cities = new NorthwindDataContext().Orders.Where(c=>c.ShipCountry == Country).Select(s => s.ShipCity).Distinct().ToList();
        List<SelectListItem> type = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var city in Cities)
        {
            if (city != null)
            {
                SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem() { Text = city.ToString(), Value = city.ToString() };
                type.Add(item);
            }
        }
        return type;
    }
    public ActionResult GetCities(string Country)  
    {
        return Json(Cities(Country), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

}